# Find numbers that are superset of another number in a list

Tags: algorithm, performance, time-complexity, bit-manipulation, coding-efficiency

A number `A` is superset of a number `B` if all bits set on `B` are also set on `A`. Or `A & B == B`.

Given a list of numbers, how can I determine all the numbers that are superset of any other number in said list?

The simple approach is:

```
for a in list:
  for b in list:
    if a != b and a & b == b:
      print(a + ' is a superset')
```

But this approach is `O(n²)`. Is there any solution more efficient?

It doesn't matter what are the subsets, only the information about supersets is needed and the list might be sorted.

Comment: When you say "all the numbers that are superset of any other number" do you mean "all the numbers that are a superset of at least one other number"?

Comment: @orlp, exactly.

Comment: If the list is sorted, we can limit the search `a > b`, but it is still O(n^2)

Comment: I don't see better than `O(n^2)`.  But sorting by the number of set bits first is likely to provide a speedup.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some improvements if the list is sorted:

```
var getSupersetList = function(sortedList){
  var supersetList = [];

  //You don't need to check the smallest element
  for (var i = sortedList.length-1; i > 0; i--) {
    var biggerElement = sortedList[i];

    //You only need to iterate over smaller elements
    for(var j = 0; j < i; j++){
      var smallerElement = sortedList[j];

      //You can get rid of the '!=' check
      if((biggerElement & smallerElement) == smallerElement){
        supersetList.push(biggerElement);

        //You can break after it is determined that it is a subset
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  //If the smallest two are duplicates (which are a subset by the logic given), add the smallest
  if(sortedList.length >= 2 && sortedList[0] == sortedList[1]){
    supersetList.push(sortedList[0]);
  } 


  return supersetList;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is still O(n²)  :/